# Installing Ubuntu in Virtual Box on mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, installation, virtualbox

I've almost completed installation. "Please remove installation media and close the tray (if any) then press ENTER:"  it says. I have pressed it,but it did nothing. I thought may be cursor is not in the ubuntu screen, but mouse integration is on.
What is "installation media" and "tray"?

Comment: "Installation media" is the CD/DVD that has the installation files, and the "tray" is the tray on your CD/DVD drive that holds the disk.

Comment: thanks. I don't have anything in the tray, as I am installing with virtualbox from iso. What could be the problem then?

Comment: I have no idea. I posted an answer to the only question you asked here. I don't use a Mac, so I've never installed Ubuntu in VirtualBox on one. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operating system has finished install and is simply asking for reboot. The installer takes precaution that if the install media is left in the drive, depending of the configured boot order this may cause the booting from it (rather than from the hard drive) and restarting the installation.

This will not happen with virtual machines. Simply reboot and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

In real computer, installation media refer to DVD disc or USB disk. In VM environment, you can just leave it and reboot is okay.